# Moodle: Give a Manager user access to "User profile fields"

Tags: moodle

I have a user who is a manger and want to grant access to the following area so they can continue editing a profile field:

Home / Site administration / Users / Accounts / User profile fields

When the user tries to access the area, they get an access is denied error.
I tried viewing the Define roles for the Manager, but couldn't find the correct one for that page.

Is this even possible?

I am on version 3.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

The user needs the `moodle/site:config` capability which will give them access to pretty much everything.

You could try creating a new capability or using an existing capability, then editing this line in `/admin/settings/users.php`

```
$ADMIN->add('users', new admin_externalpage('profilefields', new lang_string('profilefields','admin'), "$CFG->wwwroot/user/profile/index.php", array('moodle/site:config', 'newcapabilityhere')));
```

Comment: I added that line to the users.php file. Not exactly sure where would I add the capability.